# DSN file to localhost doesn't work on other computers

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010, dsn

I got an access application with a SQL Server backend and I'm trying to replicate the database for an offline version.

So every laptop got there own SQL Server database and I made a DSN file to localhost for the linked tables.

```
ODBC;Description=localhost;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;DATABASE=SMD;TABLE=dbo.ClientsListColumns
```

As I thought, it works on mine but not on the other computers

I got that error

[image]

Is there any way to make only 1 DSN file?

Thank you

Comment: It looks like the configuration is valid, but you don't have SQL Server Express installed on the target machines.

Comment: I do, the only difference is that on my machine it's express 2012 and on theirs it's 2008 R2

Comment: If you modify the connection string on the target machines, will the connection work?  If so, what do you need to change to get it working?

Comment: It works like a charm. Can you write this as an answer plz

Comment: I had to change the driver for `SQL Server Native 10` instead of SQL server. I didn't know that it would work for sql server express 2012. I was sure that SQL server would work for every versions. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the solution in this Server Fault question:

https://serverfault.com/questions/82007/how-do-i-get-this-sql-server-odbc-connection-working